# Python parse string with regex for constitute a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need extract the following string in Python to constitute a dictionary:

> 2014:02:02-12:24:17 NAMETEST ulogd[4834]: id="xxxx" severity="xxxx"
>   sys="xxxx" sub="xxxx" name="xxxx aaaa" action="xxxx" fwrule="xxxx"
>   outitf="xxxx" srcmac="xxxx" srcip="xxxx" dstip="xxxx" proto="x"
>   length="xxxx" tos="xxxx" prec="xxxx" ttl="xx" srcport="xxxx"
>   dstport="xxxx" tcpflags="xxxx"

I do not use `split(' ')` with space, because for example, the field `name="xxxx aaaa"` can contain a space.

first with the following regex I have extracted the data only:

```
re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line)
```

But now I need to used an dictionary format like: `line['id'] = 1111`.

So the regex? Have you an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find the key value pairs:

```
>>> import re
>>> groups = re.findall(r'(\w+)="(.*?)"', s)
>>> line = dict(groups)
>>>
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(line)
{'action': 'xxxx',
 'dstip': 'xxxx',
 'dstport': 'xxxx',
 'fwrule': 'xxxx',
 'id': 'xxxx',
 'length': 'xxxx',
 'name': 'xxxx aaaa',
 'outitf': 'xxxx',
 'prec': 'xxxx',
 'proto': 'x',
 'severity': 'xxxx',
 'srcip': 'xxxx',
 'srcmac': 'xxxx',
 'srcport': 'xxxx',
 'sub': 'xxxx',
 'sys': 'xxxx',
 'tcpflags': 'xxxx',
 'tos': 'xxxx',
 'ttl': 'xx'}
```

`(\w+)="(.*?)"` would match one or more alphanumeric characters (the `\w+` part), followed by `="`, followed by any characters (`.*?`, non-greedy), followed by `"`. Parenthesis here define [capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping).